Approximation the Hessian with gradient
In Hazan's book on online convex optimization (https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.05207), he presents the online Newton step algorithm for a steam of exp-concave loss functions $f_t:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ on page 62 as:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
A_0&=\epsilon I, A_t=A_{t-1}+\nabla f_t(x_t)^T\nabla f_t(x_t)\\
y_{t+1}&=x_t-\frac{1}{\gamma}A_t^{-1}\nabla f_t(x_t)\\
x_1&\in \mathcal{K},x_{t+1}=\arg\min_{x\in \mathcal{K}}\|x-y_{t+1}\|^{2}_{A_t}~,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $\mathcal{K}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\epsilon,\gamma>0$ are given parameters.
I know the Newton method for offline optimization, which corresponds to the case in which all loss functions are the same $f_t=f$ and we use the Hessian $\nabla^2f(x_t)$ instead of $A_t$ to calculate the updates. Could someone shed some light on why $A_t$ as defined here is a good first-order approximation for some notion of a Hessian? Note that the loss functions are assumed to be exp-concave throughout.
Thank you!
